# Program to list all files in a folder with user specified extension not working

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program to which asks user to specify a file extension. It then lists all the available files with that extension in the `textarea`. I made the following program. However my compiler shows error in `endsWith()` statement and only the first file name is printed if I run the program without the `endsWith()`.

Any help identifying the issue is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class search extends Thread implements ActionListener
{
JFrame f;
JButton bop,bser;
JTextField tf,text;
JTextArea ta;
JLabel lab,lab1;
String str;
JScrollPane scrol;
File fl;

search()
{
    f=new JFrame("Search box");
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setSize(820,700);

    bop=new JButton("Open");
    bop.setBounds(50,600,180,30);
    bop.addActionListener(this);
    f.add(bop);

    lab=new JLabel("Extension");
    lab.setBounds(340,570,180,30);
    f.add(lab);


    bser=new JButton("Search");
    bser.setBounds(510,600,180,30);
    bser.addActionListener(this);
    f.add(bser);    

    text=new JTextField();
    text.setBounds(280,600,180,30);
    text.addActionListener(this);
    text.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    f.add(text);

    tf=new JTextField();
    tf.setBounds(25,50,750,40);
    tf.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console",Font.BOLD,20));
    tf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    f.add(tf);

    ta=new JTextArea();
    scrol=new JScrollPane(ta);
    //JScrollPane.setPreferredSize(750,450);
    scrol.setBounds(25,100,750,450);

    f.add(scrol);



    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Open"))
    {
        FileDialog fd=new FileDialog(f,"Open Box",FileDialog.LOAD);
        fd.setSize(300,300);
        fd.setVisible(true);
        str=fd.getDirectory();
        tf.setText(str);                    
    }

    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Search"))
    {
        fl=new File(str);
        File[] flist=fl.listFiles();

        for (int i=0;i<flist.length;i++)
        {
            String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            String nm=text.getText();
            if(flist[i].endsWith(nm))
            {
                if(flist[i].isFile())
                {
                    ta.setText(flist[i].getName()+newline);
                }       
            }
        }               
    }
}   

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new search();
    }

}
```

the compiler is giving no error. its just that when i run the program... and feed in a directory path, as soon as i press search, only one file name is displayed in the textarea... and even if i dont enter anything in the textfield , and the if condition isnt satisfied, then also the same thing happens.

Comment: Why not show the error? Seems like that would be useful information. You need to get the filename in order to call a string method on it, AFAIK; there's no `endsWith()` on `File`.

Comment: What's error shows you compiler at that line?

Comment: Why are you extending Thread?

Comment: @SLaks i would be extending this program further... so i extended thread coz i'l need it later on

Comment: @UditRaizada: You aren't saving yourself anytime by doing that now. It's also better to implement `Runnable` as your class isn't concerned with how a `Thread` works and it gives you more flexibility in the future when you run concurrent tasks.

Comment: @unholysampler thanks.. i will keep that in mind.. 
but cn u help me out ? my program still aint giving proper output.

Comment: @UditRaizada: In order for us to help, you need to: Say what error(s) you are getting. Indicate the line the error(s) are occurring on. If the code compiles and runs, specify the output you are getting for a specific input and the output you are expecting. You can edit the question to provide this additional information.

Answer (score 3):

There's no `File.endsWith()`, you need to get the file's name:

```
flist[i].getName().endsWith(nm)
```

You might also want to make sure it's a file (not a directory) just in case.

Comment: yeah i did check it through

     if(flist[i].isFile())

Answer (score 1):

You need to say file.getName().endsWith( suffix );

Also, if you press Search without first pressing Open, I noticed that "str" is not being defined.  You will get a null pointer exception here.  You might want to check for that.

EDIT **

Try the following code.  I have modified it so that it works.  There is a defect in the way you wrote the code that results in a defect, though.  You'll see it I'm sure.  Fixing that defect should not be too tough for you.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test extends Thread implements ActionListener
{
  JFrame f;

  JButton bop, bser;

  JTextField tf, text;

  JTextArea ta;

  JLabel lab, lab1;

  String str;

  JScrollPane scrol;

  File fl;

  Test()
{
    f = new JFrame( "Search box" );
    f.setLayout( null );
    f.setSize( 820, 700 );

    bop = new JButton( "Open" );
    bop.setBounds( 50, 600, 180, 30 );
    bop.addActionListener( this );
    f.add( bop );

    lab = new JLabel( "Extension" );
    lab.setBounds( 340, 570, 180, 30 );
    f.add( lab );


    bser = new JButton( "Search" );
    bser.setBounds( 510, 600, 180, 30 );
    bser.addActionListener( this );
    bser.setEnabled( false );
    f.add( bser );

    text = new JTextField();
    text.setBounds( 280, 600, 180, 30 );
    text.addActionListener( this );
    text.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.CENTER );
    f.add( text );

    tf = new JTextField();
    tf.setBounds( 25, 50, 750, 40 );
    tf.setFont( new Font( "Lucida Console", Font.BOLD, 20 ) );
    tf.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.CENTER );
    f.add( tf );

    ta = new JTextArea();
    scrol = new JScrollPane( ta );
    //JScrollPane.setPreferredSize(750,450);
    scrol.setBounds( 25, 100, 750, 450 );

    f.add( scrol );

    f.setVisible( true );
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );


  }

  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
  {
    if ( ae.getActionCommand().equals( "Open" ) )
    {
      FileDialog fd = new FileDialog( f, "Open Box", FileDialog.LOAD );
      fd.setSize( 300, 300 );
      fd.setVisible( true );
      str = fd.getDirectory();

      if ( str != null && !str.trim().equals( "" ) )
      {
        tf.setText( str );

        // Enable the search button
        bser.setEnabled( true );
      }
      else
      {
        bser.setEnabled( false );
      }
    }

    if ( ae.getActionCommand().equals( "Search" ) )
    {
      fl = new File( str );
      File[] flist = fl.listFiles();

      for ( int i = 0; i < flist.length; i++ )
      {
        String newline = System.getProperty( "line.separator" );
        String nm = text.getText();
        if ( flist[i].getName().toLowerCase().endsWith( nm.toLowerCase() ) )
        {
          if ( flist[i].isFile() )
          {
            ta.setText( flist[i].getName() + newline );
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    new Test();
  }
}
```

Comment: ohk thanks a lot for telling me abt dat exception..i just did what u asked me i.e change it to getName().endsWith();
still the same problem persists..

Comment: i am perplexed abt it .. i guess theres some problem in the loop. i m new to java

Comment: i tried ur code in my computer.. i agree that the null pointer exception got removed... but still it aint working as expectd

Comment: Well, more specific details are needed, then.  If the code doesn't work as expected, you have to be extremely specific about how you want it to work.  Something like, "First, I want to do A.  Then, I want B to happen.  Then, I do C.  At that point, I want D to happen."  But just saying "it isn't working as expected" is not detailed enough for anyone to give you the help you need.

Comment: oh ok sorry.. well as u asked me to explain... First i want to open a folder . as i do so. i want the path of that folder to be displayed in the TextField tf. then after entering the desired extension in the TextField text ,i want that as i click search button,all the files with the extension specified in the text field are displayed in the TextArea ta. all the steps happen as desired , but when i click the search button, only one file name with the desired extension is displayed in the textarea. not all the filenames. 

i guess now u understand my problem

Comment: Yes, and that last problem is the defect that I said you will find.  :-)  Currently, your code is not showing all of the files.  Only one.  So really take a look at the code and try to understand why it is doing it.  You have a loop... which is great.  But look at the couple of things you are doing in that loop.  With those couple things, will *all* of the files show?  Which file is being shown?  Give it a second look and if you don't find it, come back.

Comment: i tried analysing the code again... m sorry but i am not able to find the glitch.. so if u cn please help me ... i would really be thankfull.

Comment: The problem is that you are calling setText() in the loop.  This method will *replace* what is currently in the textfield.  What you should be doing is building/appending a string in the loop, and then after the loop, call setText with the string that has all of the file names in it.

Comment: ohh yeaaaah!! now i realise .. if i add ta.setText( ta.getText()+flist[i].getName() + newline ); den also it wrks fine
thnks a lot anyways

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.  Remember on StackOverflow to accept the answer if this works for you now.  That's the way we keep on helping others.  Thanks!

Comment: @mightyrick :So far from this code The file names are displaying in a textarea right! My query is:I need to put a checkbox on each file in the textarea and also "select all" checkbox so that I can generate the ticked files to another path(using Jfile chooser)Destination output . So I can apply my method in this process? Is that possible.:)

Comment: @RamKi, this is really a different question then the original question.  I don't have time to rewrite all of this code.  But I can tell you that you will need to change this from putting the filenames in a single a JTextArea to looping over each name and creating a JCheckBox with the filename as the JCheckBox label.  So a "new JCheckBox(fileName)" for each file.  Then, you probably need to add each JCheckBox to a JScrollPane.  There's lots of good documentation out there on how to use Swing to accomplish this.  Thanks.

Comment: @RamKi, another option would be to use a JComboBox in multiple select mode.  It might be a better option because this Swing component will scroll all by itself.  So no need to use a complicated layout or anything.